# How to display embedded MongoDB document in Laravel Blade?

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-blade

Hello everyone i want to display the owner name in the laravel blade from this document.

I can display the name and description using foreach loop but not from the embedded document.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58c1b173ebda1297b747271b"),
        "name" : "Name of Board",
        "description" : "Board short description",
        "postdate" : ISODate("2016-12-19T06:01:17.171Z"),
        "owner" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("58c13ebaebda1297b747271a"),
                        "name" : "Joker"
                }
        ],
        "tag" : {

        },
        "subscribers" : [
                {

                }
        ],
        "likes" : [
                ObjectId("58c13ebaebda1297b747271a")
        ]
}
```

Please kindly help. thank you in advance

Comment: owner field's value is an array that has got another array inside of it. Loop with nested foreach.

Comment: @Josip i tried this (https://paste.laravel.io/on2P1) and (https://paste.laravel.io/LKqOM) But not working

Comment: try like this... u need to loop owner again cause it's array containing array... https://paste.laravel.io/Zo7qM

Comment: @Josip it does not work. i get `Property [owner] does not exist on this collection instance.` when i used the code provided. But when i use this https://paste.laravel.io/YAnqM i get Undefined property: MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID::$name. here is the dump https://paste.laravel.io/xnV3o

Answer (score 0):

As it's nested array you need to access it with foreach...

```
@foreach ($boards as $board)
    <p>{{ $board->name }}</p>
    @foreach ($board->owner as $ownerArray)
    <p>{{ $ownerArray['name'] }}</p>
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
```

Comment: sorry, it does not work. I get this error `Cannot use object of type MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID as array` at line 3

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I changed the way I am storing the data.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58c1d1a48c2201423599f7fd"),
        "name" : "Name of Board2",
        "description" : "Board short description",
        "postdate" : ISODate("2016-12-19T06:01:17.171Z"),
        "owner" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("58c13ebaebda1297b747271a"),
                "name" : "Joker"
        },
        "tag" : {

        },
        "subscribers" : [
                {

                }
        ],
        "likes" : [
                ObjectId("58c13ebaebda1297b747271a")
        ]
}
```

Then i accessed it by

```
@foreach ($boards as $board)
    <p>{{ $board->name }}</p>

    <p>{{ $board['owner']['name'] }}</p>

  @endforeach
```